# auto_arima - Schur decomposition solver error error

Tags: python, time-series, arima

I'm following [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/anomaly-detection-with-time-series-forecasting-c34c6d04b24a) article to write an anomaly detection program, and my stepwise model seems to be generating `LinAlgError: Schur decomposition solver error.` I've seen [people](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55109912/how-to-solve-linalgerror-valueerror-when-training-arima-model-with-python/55153918) have the same issue with the ARIMA function, and have tried adding the parameters `enforce_stationarity=False, enforce_invertibility=False` but the problem persists.

```
from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima
import math
import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.tsa.api as smt
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
stepwise_model = auto_arima(train_log, start_p=1, start_q=1,
                           max_p=3, max_q=3, m=7,
                           start_P=0, seasonal=True,
                           d=1, D=1, trace=True,
                           error_action='ignore',  
                           suppress_warnings=True, 
                           stepwise=True)

train, test = actual_vals[0:-70], actual_vals[-70:]
train_log, test_log = np.log10(train), np.log10(test)
# split data into train and test-sets
history = [x for x in train_log]
predictions = list()
predict_log=list()
for t in range(len(test_log)):
    stepwise_model.fit(history)
    output = stepwise_model.predict(n_periods=1)
    predict_log.append(output[0])
    yhat = 10**output[0]
    predictions.append(yhat)
    obs = test_log[t]
    history.append(obs)

# plot
figsize=(12, 7)
plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
pyplot.plot(test,label='Actuals')
pyplot.plot(predictions, color='red',label='Predicted')
pyplot.legend(loc='upper right')
pyplot.show()
```

You should be able to replicate the error by replacing actual_vals with the value column of a time series data frame? But if not, my data is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Br5_PcjXyyoYjM1KpW8Q3cVYtXPGHMK0/view?usp=sharing). You can read it with `df=pd.read_csv('/Users/main/Downloads/Stage.csv', header=14,low_memory=False)`. Although I encountered some errors working with the csv data, so you might have to read it from an sql database.